# How do I get the xpath, or other locators?

Tags: css, xpath, webdriver

I needed help to get the best possible element locator can I use for a button with the following code;

```
<button onclick="btnProcess($(this), 'Adding...','fa-refresh fa-spin',0);callServer('/DejavuMobile/action/UserGroupModel_AddItem/Users/Add?hfUsername=8_44&amp;ic=44&amp;hfService=', function(response){ btnProcess($(this), 'Add new item','fa-plus',1);loadContent($('#UserAddUI') ,response); });" class="btn btn-xs btn-labeled btn-info" type="button" style="padding-right:12px;padding-left:12px;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:15px;"><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Add new Group</button>
```

Comment: Show what have you tried already

Answer (score 2):

The most readable one:

```
//button[text()='Add new Group']
```

It's possible to create path using class or any other attribute, but by text in this case is the most clear and easy way.

Comment: Thank you for this quick response. I will try it out immediately. I appreciate.

Comment: you are welcome. In case of any issue do not hesitate to ask, path could be adjusted to any requirements)